# Removing common junks from tweets for topic modeling

Tags: python, string, list, url, twitter

I am trying to remove common junks like `RT`, all the strings starting with `@`, and all the URLs. The way I treated it was like this:

```
prefixes=["http","ftp","@","#","RT"]

for prefix in prefixes:
            for word in final_tweet:
                    if word.startswith(prefix):
                            print "starts with prefix"
                            word=''
```

while this code sometimes removes junks (and always detects the junk), it doesn't always remove them. So I wonder what the problem could be?

Here's some examples of the output:

```
['RT', '@NadelParis:', 'Going2LOVEorKILL?Download', 'NOW!', 'https://t.co/xilNh66e34', '@CrookedIntriago', '@Seven13music', '@UMG', '\xe3\x82\x8f\xe3\x81\x9f\xe3\x81\x97\xe3\x81\xaf\xe3\x80\x81\xe3\x81\x82\xe3\x81\xaa\xe3\x81\x9f\xe3\x82\x92\xe6\x84\x9b\xe3\x81\x97\xe3\x81\xa6\xe3\x81\x84\xe3\x81\xbe\xe3\x81\x99!', 'RTPlz<3', 'https:/\xe2\x80\xa6']
starts with prefix
starts with prefix
starts with prefix
starts with prefix
starts with prefix
starts with prefix
starts with prefix
starts with prefix
['Going2LOVEorKILL?Download', 'NOW!', 'https://t.co/xilNh66e34', '@CrookedIntriago', '@Seven13music', '@UMG', '\xe3\x82\x8f\xe3\x81\x9f\xe3\x81\x97\xe3\x81\xaf\xe3\x80\x81\xe3\x81\x82\xe3\x81\xaa\xe3\x81\x9f\xe3\x82\x92\xe6\x84\x9b\xe3\x81\x97\xe3\x81\xa6\xe3\x81\x84\xe3\x81\xbe\xe3\x81\x99!', 'RTPlz<3', 'https://t.co/I40s8x3QAV']

['RT', '@dbrandSkins:', 'Dear', 'Apple,', 'T9', 'dialing', 'optional.', 'Get', 'shit', 'together.', 'Signed,\nEveryone']
starts with prefix
starts with prefix
['Dear', 'Apple,', 'T9', 'dialing', 'optional.', 'Get', 'shit', 'together.', 'Signed,\nEveryone']
['RT', '@WeLoveRobDyrdek:', 'This', 'dog', '', 'https://t.co/5N86jYipOI']
null found
starts with prefix
starts with prefix
starts with prefix
['This', 'dog', '', 'https://t.co/5N86jYipOI']
null found
starts with prefix
['RT', '@sayingsforgirls:', 'Do', 'touch', 'MY', 'iPhone.', "It's", 'usPhone,', 'wePhone,', 'ourPhone,']
starts with prefix
starts with prefix
['Do', 'touch', 'MY', 'iPhone.', "It's", 'usPhone,', 'wePhone,', 'ourPhone,']
['RT', '@BrianaaSymonee:', 'says', 'imma', 'dog,', 'takes', 'one', 'know', 'one...']
starts with prefix
starts with prefix
['says', 'imma', 'dog,', 'takes', 'one', 'know', 'one...']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer given by someone at #Python IRC channel:

```
final_tweet = [word for word in final_tweet if not any (word.startswith(prefix) for prefix in prefixes)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check for each prefix

```
>>> for prefix in prefixes:
...     final_tweet = [ w for w in final_tweet if not w.startswith(prefix)]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! You could improve the answer by explaining what you changed versus the code the question already has posted, why you changed it and how it should now behave. Code only answers - even if they do help the asker - are of less value to the community in the long run than answers with good explanations.